# Prisma update data with relation and where-clause

Tags: mysql, node.js, prisma

I want to update data with a relation to other tables, but I don't really find a solution for that. I'm using Prisma in a NodeJS-Application. I give the id (Number(req.params.id)) in the URL.

For example: http://localhost:3000/api/apprentice/42

**schema.prisma:**

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model apprentice {
  apId          Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
  geId          Int         @db.TinyInt
  apFirstname   String      @db.VarChar(50)
  apLastname    String      @db.VarChar(50)
  apBirthdate   DateTime?   @db.Date
  apPhoneNumber String      @db.VarChar(12)
  gender        gender      @relation(fields: [geId], references: [geId], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction, map: "fk_apprentice_gender1")
  execution     execution[]

  @@index([geId], map: "fk_apprentice_gender1_idx")
}

model execution {
  exId       Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  reId       Int        @db.TinyInt
  apId       Int
  exDate     DateTime   @db.DateTime(0)
  exMessage  String     @db.VarChar(8000)
  apprentice apprentice @relation(fields: [apId], references: [apId], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: NoAction, map: "execution_ibfk_1")
  region     region     @relation(fields: [reId], references: [reId], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction, map: "fk_execution_region1")

  @@index([apId], map: "execution_ibfk_1")
  @@index([reId], map: "fk_execution_region1_idx")
}

model gender {
  geId       Int          @id @db.TinyInt
  gender     String       @db.VarChar(6)
  apprentice apprentice[]
}

model message {
  meId      Int    @id @default(autoincrement()) @db.TinyInt
  reId      Int    @db.TinyInt
  meMessage String @db.VarChar(8000)
  region    region @relation(fields: [reId], references: [reId], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction, map: "fk_message_region1")

  @@index([reId], map: "fk_message_region1_idx")
}

model region {
  reId      Int         @id @db.TinyInt
  reOrt     String      @db.VarChar(50)
  execution execution[]
  message   message[]
}
```

**Request in server.js (NodeJS):**

```
app.put("/api/apprentice/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const updatedApprentice = await prisma.apprentice.update({
    where: {
      apId: Number(req.params.id)
    },
    data: {
      gender: {
        update: {
          geId: req.body.apprentice.gender,
        }
      },
      apFirstname: req.body.apprentice.firstName,
      apLastname: req.body.apprentice.lastName,
      apBirthdate: new Date(req.body.apprentice.birthdate),
      apPhoneNumber: req.body.apprentice.phoneNumber,
      execution: {
        update: {
          exDate: req.body.execution.datetime,
          exMessage: req.body.execution.message,
          reId: req.body.region
        }
      }
    }
  });
  res.send(updatedApprentice);
});
```

**Request body:**

```
{
    "execution": {
        "datetime": "2022-06-12 10:30:00",
        "message": "test for 3 und Person name1 name2 am 2022-06-14 um 07:00:00"
    },
    "apprentice": {
        "firstName": "name1",
        "lastName": "name2",
        "birthdate": "2005-06-29",
        "gender": 2,
        "phoneNumber": "+41111111111"
    },
    "region": 1
}
```

**MySQL-Schema**
[image]

Comment: What is the intended relationship between `apprentice` and `execution`? Is it one-to-one (each apprentice only has one execution) or one-to-many (each apprentice has many executions)? If it is one-to-many, are you trying to update only the newest `execution`?

Comment: It is a one-to-many relationship and yes, I only want to update the newest.

Answer (score 1):

Here you need two queries, the first one being to find the latest execution row:

```js
const latestExId = (
  await prisma.execution.findFirst({
    where: {
      apId: Number(req.params.id),
    },
    orderBy: { exDate: "desc" },
    select: { exId: true },
  })
)?.exId;
if (!latestExId) {
  throw new Error("This apprentice has no executions ongoing");
}

const updatedApprentice = await prisma.apprentice.update({
  where: {
    apId: Number(req.params.id),
  },
  data: {
    geId: req.body.apprentice.gender,
    apFirstname: req.body.apprentice.firstName,
    apLastname: req.body.apprentice.lastName,
    apBirthdate: new Date(req.body.apprentice.birthdate),
    apPhoneNumber: req.body.apprentice.phoneNumber,
    execution: {
      update: {
        data: {
          exDate: req.body.execution.datetime,
          exMessage: req.body.execution.message,
          reId: req.body.region,
        },
        where: {
          exId: latestExId,
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

(I have not tested this code)

It also seems to me that you meant to update the `geId` field of the apprentice, rather than to update the `geId` of the gender table. Note that you could use an [enum](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/data-model#defining-enums) or simply a string field for the apprentice's gender value instead of having a specific table for gender.

Comment: Thanks! 
If someone wants to use this solution, will probably need to remove 'data: {}' (in the execution). After mentioned removal it worked for me